# Using pd.merge to aggregate multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is the code to merge two dataframes and get mean of a particular column like below,

```
pd.merge(df_old.loc[~df_old[‘COL1’].isnull()],
                      df_new,
                      on=’ID’)[‘COL1_y’].isnull().mean()
```

How do I repeat this for multiple columns (COL2, COL3…) without loop? I want to do it column wise. So that mean is there for each column

Here is my solution, is there a better way of doing this?

```
src = pd.Series()
for col in ['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3']:
    src[col]=pd.merge(df_old.loc[~df_old[col].isnull()],
                          df_new,
                          on=’ID’)[col+'_y'].isnull().mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

IICU, you want to merge on multiple column at once.

```
import pandas as pd
df_old=pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0,'1','2','3',10],
        [0,'1','2','3',20],
        [1,'1','2','3',30],
        [1,'1','2','3',40],
        [3,'1','2','3',50],

    ],
    columns=['ID','COL1','COL2','COL3','x'])
df_new=pd.DataFrame(   
     [
        [0,'1','2','3',50],
        [0,'1','2','3',40],
        [1,'1','2','3',30],
        [1,'1','2','3',20],
        [3,'1','2','3',10],

    ],columns=['ID','COL1','COL2','COL3','y'])
df_merge=pd.merge(df_old,df_new,on=['ID','COL1','COL2','COL3'], how='left')
df_merge
```

And you will get this

|  | ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 10 | 50 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 20 | 50 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 20 | 40 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 30 | 30 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 30 | 20 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 40 | 30 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 40 | 20 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 50 | 10 |

And if you want the mean of `y` after merge,

```
df_merge['y'].mean()
```

Then you will get

```
32.22222222222222
```

Please state the result you expect, it is more easy to help you.

Hope this help.

Comment: Need to apply the merge to each column, so that mean is calculated for every column seperately